# ExpressJS + SQLite3 - how to pass parameters into IN statement?

Tags: javascript, express, node-sqlite3

I want to build a simple e-commerce site where each product is unique (each has exactly one quantity; all are stored as a separate integer) using **ExpressJS** and **SQLite3**.

My problem is with writing a query which gets all the specified products. I thought the best idea is to run query like `SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id IN (...)`, where in dots there would be a list of specific product IDs to select from.

I wanted to build such a query using a module **SQLite3** with **ExpressJS**. The problem is it always prints `undefined` instead of list of products. I do not know why is that.

## How my does table schema look like?

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const DB_PATH = "products.db";
const db = new sqlite3.Database(DB_PATH);

db.serialize(() => {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products ( \
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \
    name TEXT NOT NULL \
  )")
})

module.exports = db;
```

## How was my approach to run the query using module `SQLite3`?

```js
const db = require('./database');

function getProductsFromCart(request) {
  if (request.session.cart && request.session.cart.length > 0) {
    let sql = "SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id IN (?";
    for (let i = 1; i < request.session.cart.length; i++) {
      sql += ", ?";
    }
    sql += ")"
    const params = request.session.cart;
    let products = undefined;
    db.all(sql, params, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(rows);
      products = rows;
    });
    console.log(products);
    return products;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

What could be the problem? Is data binding created correctly? I tried to find solutions using StackOverflow. There was only one similar problem, but I am not sure about correctness. That's why I am asking. Thanks in advance!